# What is the differences between version control system (say : Subversion) and document management system?

Tags: svn, version-control, dms

DMS : Centralized Document Storage, management access, keep track document, security, authentification, etc.

Version control, example like Subversion : instead of DMS featur above, Subversion : merge, create graph, etc.

but I really confusing the basic thing which differ DMS and subversion ?

Comment: What would you consider a DMS?

Comment: I have to collaborate in writting documents in .tex,.lyx,.oop,.docs files. which is the best tool would be used?DMS or SVN?and why?

Answer (score 2):

Both version control systems (VCS) and document management systems (DMS) share a set of common feature:

1. Both of them keep a set of entities, either source files or official documents.
2. Both are able to assign a set of properties to each entity, e.g. author, date, etc.
3. Both keep the entire history of stored items.
4. Both should authenticate users before accessing the entities.
5. Check-in and Check-out is a common concept in both cases.
6. Export and importing folders and files are common features of both cases.

But there are a set of differences between theses two:

1. VCSs are designed for software developers, but DMSs are designed for
   end users that work with documents, e.g. secretaries.
2. There are some essential features in a DMS that are not common on
   VCSs, such as:

   - Sending a document for another user
   - Importing a document from external sources, such as scanner, fax, email, etc.
   - Reporting on documents with complex filters and queries.
   - Supporting of reminders, document workflows, following up the result of a document, erc.

On the other hand, a set of features are more common and essential in VCSs:

1. Merging and branching a product line.
2. Integration with issue tracking systems.
3. Returning back the whole repository to an old revision

Answer (score 1):

Version control systems support many more features related to software development.
Including but not limited to: checkout, merging, branching, labeling, integration, ...
These features are used to handle multiple users changing  a file(s) at the same time,   and tracking/branching when a software product is released, moving changes from one brach to another, ...

Document management systems are more for end users to save and collaborate documents.  They can support versioned documents, but lack the features listed above.

See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Revision_control for more information about version control systems